# Additive blending with Core Graphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics

How can I blend two images in additive blending mode with Core Graphics?

The enum does **not** have something like a `kCGBlendModeAdd`: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGBlendMode

Any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is wrong with `kCGBlendModePlusLighter`?

From the linked document:

```
R = MIN(1, S + D)
```

So that is an additive blending capped at 1.0.

Comment: Thanks. Note to self: take some coffee before asking obvious questions on SO.